# How to set Universal proxy(not proxy server) on windows xp

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-xp, universal

how can i set up a universal proxy on windows xp and i am not talking about setting up proxy server,
in fact i have a proxy server setup on my localhost:8889 port and i have set it to accept connections only from 127.0.0.1 but

now i have to specifically set proxy, in each application to use this proxy server. 
Is there any other option like setting up universal proxy means all data/traffic from windows will go through that ip:port of proxy server so that i don't have to specifically set it on each application.

also some of my application uses random proxy server so , anybody here know how to do it?

i think i have seen it somewhere in Linux,

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Windows program use the proxy set in the Internet Option --> Lan settings.
Other programs might decide to use the system proxy or to have their own proxy details entry. It's down to the program you install.